# Mysqli can't insert multiple rows

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
$allgames = file_get_contents("https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=all");
$decodeall = json_decode($allgames, true);
foreach($decodeall as $game) {



$sql = "INSERT INTO games (name)
VALUES ('{$game['name']}')";

}

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

When i do this only the first row will be added. How do i insert multiple rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of that multi query thing. Use a prepared statement instead

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO games (name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
foreach($decodeall as $game) {
    $name = $game['name'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
echo "New records created successfully";
```

Note that your current code with multi_query won't work as intended anyway, even with that silly typo fixed. You will have the result of only first query,  having no idea what happened to all others.

Comment: @bonitzenator nope, you don't. both cases you mention will go without multiple query just perfectly. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the query each time. Try setting sql to blank then appending it each time in the loop.

Try this:

```
$sql = array();
foreach($decodeall as $game) {

$sql[] = "INSERT INTO games (name) VALUES ('{$game['name']}')";
}

$sqlInserts = implode(';', $sql);

if ($conn->multi_query($sqlInserts) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... i tried that but now it gives me the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO games (name) VALUES ('Team Fortress 2')INSERT INTO games (name) VALU' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The sql insert statements need be be concatenated with a  semicolon.  I've edited the answer, please try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time helping me out, i really appreciate it. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform the query multiple times like that, you can do it all in a single query without `multi_query()`. You can perform many INSERTs with a single query, like this

```
// Initialize the query-variable
$sql = "INSERT INTO games (name) VALUES";

// Loop through results and add to the query
foreach ($decodeall as $game) {
    $sql .= " ('".$game['name']."'),";
}

// Remove the last comma with rtrim
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');

// Perform the query
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

This will generate a query resembling

```
INSERT INTO games (name) VALUES ('One'), ('two'), ('Three')
```

which will insert the values `One`, `Two` and `Three` into separate rows.

This query will *break* if your `$game['name']` variables contain an apostrophy `'`, so at the very least you should use [`$mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), although a prepared statement takes care of that **and** prevents SQL injection (so I recommend you go for that instead). See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

**Using a prepared statement - the better solution**
The preferred method of executing a query is by using a prepared statement.

Fetch all the columns using `array_column()` and loop the array while calling the execute method until finished.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO games (name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
foreach (array_column($decode, "name") as $name) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! But the query breaks because of the apostrophy '. I will try using prepared statement and definitely read up on SQL injection. Thanks for pointing that out.